# Reading a path from another project in the same server and directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two projects running on the server:

- Project1
- Project2

Urls to my catalogues

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project1\Folder1\

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project2\wwwroot\Folder1\
```

**Project1** - Web Aplication in Net Framework

**Project2** -  API REST in .Net Core 2.2

Is there a way for me to read the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project1\` from `Project2` ?

The reason is the common catalog for both projects located in Project1

I don't want to do it manually. I am looking for a different way. Maybe it can be read from the IIS level?

Comment: Are you saying you want to somehow get the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project1\` dynamically? Like some method that you would just know "Project1" and be able to determine where that app resides? If so, then no it's not possible. Only Project1 would know where Project1 resides. You cannot get that information from Project2. However, the better approach here would be move the common files out into a mutually shared location that is independent of either app. Then, as long as that location does not change, you can move either app wherever you like.

Comment: @ChrisPratt We know that both applications are in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`  I know that they are in the same directory and on the same server.  I think this is already some information

Comment: @ChrisPratt The only thing we don't know is the name of the project directory. `Project1` is the name only to show here the question

Comment: If you don't know the name of the project directory, then what should the computer do? If you can guarantee it will always be in the wwwroot folder then you can just provide the name of the other project folder in the config file, something like that. Then put the two together in order to find the path. But you know what...you said "The reason is the common catalog for both projects located in Project1"...that's fundamentally a bad design, creating a dependency from one to the other. As Chris said, you should have a shared area which doesn't change, and doesn't belong to either project.